# На NAS'е папка стала файлом

Tags: linux, объекты, nas, nextcloud

Имеется:

- Сервер с установленным Nextcloud (аля домашний Dropbox)
- NAS QNAP, примонтированный к серверу

В настройках Nextcloud'а в качестве места хранения указан примонтированный NAS.

В какой-то момент погас свет и оба устройства (сервер с облаком и хранилище) *нештатно* завершили свою работу. После запуска обнаружилось, что некоторые объекты, которые до этого были **директориями**, стали **файлами** и теперь к ним, собственно, никак не подобраться.

Есть ли возможность как-либо достать и спасти содержимое этих "файлов-папок"?

Comment: Ну `fsck` ты делал и оно не помогло?

Comment: К сожалению не помогло.

Comment: В итоге вся ситуация ничем не разрешилась, файлы были утеряны, на вопросе поставили крест.